# android signing with platform keys versus uploadkeys

Tags: android

I am developing for a closed platform and need to sign my apk with platform keys to be able to read from certain protected libraries. since this app additionally is not available on the Google Play store, does this mean that I don't need to sign with any other public private key pair for a release build? currently my workflow is such that we first create the build with `gradlew assembleRelease` which I assume uses the `local.properties` to sign my apk given the current build.gradle setup:

```
    release {
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
        storeFile file('./debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
    }
```

if I am subsequently using `apksigner` to sign with the platform credentials, does that render the aforementioned release `build.gradle` config pointless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the gradle configuration is used for a particular build type, or the alternative is to use `zipalign` and `apksigner` on the apk generated from the gradle task. So if i wanted to continue using `apksigner` i should remove the build.gradle configuration. I guess theoretically it was signing again the app twice, but since the last one was the non-debug keys, it didn't really matter.

For reference:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#gradle_signing